# How to draw arrows below nodes in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I want to replicate the following drawing with TikZ in beamer, with slight changes to the names.

[image]

Currently, I have something like this, but it is not exactly what I want. The lines are next to the nodes and not below, and also I do not know how to write stuff below the nodes and put arrows there. Initially in the slide there should be only the nodes and the text below and above the nodes. Then, on the next transition the line with PreSign should appear, then the arrow from right to left, then the line with Adapt, then the arrow from left to right, and finally the line with Ext. How can I achieve this with TikZ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    calc,
    chains,
    decorations,
    decorations.text,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    matrix,
    positioning,
    shapes,
    tikzmark
}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Protocol View}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]
% nodes
\node[alice,minimum size=1.5cm] (s) at (0,0) {$(Y,y) \in R$};
\node[bob,minimum size=1.5cm,right of=s] (r) {$(\mathsf{pk},\mathsf{sk})$};
% paths
\draw [->] (r) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center] {$\hat{\sigma}$} (s);
\draw [->] ($(s.east)+(1em,-1em)$) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center] {$\sigma$} ($(r.west)+(-1em,-1em)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: a handrawn sketch of the desired output would be better appreciated

Comment: @jsbibra Well the desired output is the picture in the post, just using the nodes specified in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `matrix` (or `tikz-cd`) along with `overlay-beamer-styles`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    matrix,
    overlay-beamer-styles
}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Protocol View}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ar/.style={very thick,-latex},nodes={font=\small}]

\matrix[column sep=1.8cm,matrix of math nodes,
ampersand replacement=\&,
row 3/.style={nodes={visible on=<2->}},
row 4/.style={nodes={visible on=<4->}},
row 5/.style={nodes={visible on=<6->}}]  (m) {
|[alice,minimum size=1.5cm]| (Y,y) \in R \&
|[bob,minimum size=1.5cm]| (\mathsf{pk},\mathsf{sk})\\
pk,M \& y,M\\
\& \hat\sigma\leftarrow\operatorname{PreSign}\bigl((pk,sk),y,M\bigr)\\
\sigma\leftarrow\operatorname{Adap}\bigl((Y,y),p,k,M\bigr) \&\\
\& y'\leftarrow\operatorname{Ext}(y,\hat\sigma,\sigma)\\
};
\path (m-3-2.south west) -- coordinate (p1) (m-3-2.west|-m-4-1.north)
 (m-5-2.north west) -- coordinate (p2) (m-5-2.west|-m-4-1.south);
\draw[ar,visible on=<5->] (p1) -- node[above]{$\hat\sigma$} (p1-|m-4-1.east);
\draw[ar,visible on=<7->] (p2-|m-4-1.east) -- node[above]{$\sigma$} (p2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works nicely!